# How to get my real IP using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

How to get my real IP using vb.net?

Comment: There is no IP address that is more or less "real" than any other, so which IP address is it that you want really?

Comment: @Guffa probably 127.0.0.1 :P but that's just metaphysical speculation

Comment: @Federico Culloca: Curse you!  Beat me to it...

Comment: Do you mean the "public" IP that is returned by websites such as [whatismyip.com](http://whatismyip.com)?

Comment: @Jeff: Well, that is what people usually ask for. On the other hand, the answer to that is easily found with a search, so it's possible that the OP is looking for something completely different...

Answer (score 2):

If you are running in ASP.NET, then use the [HttpRequest.UserHostAddress property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress.aspx):

```
Dim ip as string
ip = Request.UserHostAddress()
```

Answer (score 1):

Create php script. Save it as realip.php

```
<?php
echo $this->getRealIpAddr();


function getRealIpAddr()
    {
        $ip = "";
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
        {
          $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
        elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
        {
        $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
        else
        {
            $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
        return $ip;
    }
?>
```

In your VB.net project create a module.
Declare the imports section at the very top

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
```

And create your function:

```
    Public Function GetIP() As String

    Dim uri_val As New Uri("http://yourdomain.com/realip.php")
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri_val)

    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get

    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    Dim myIP As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

    response.Close()

    Return myIP
End Function
```

Now anywhere in your code you can issue

```
Dim myIP as String = GetIP()
```

as use the value from there as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](http://waqarahmadbhatti.blogspot.com/2010/10/perfect-way-to-get-client-ip-address-in.html) (how and why), the best way to get the client IP is:

```
Dim clientIP As String
Dim ip As String = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ip) Then
    Dim ipRange As String() = ip.Trim().Split(","C)
    Dim le As Integer = ipRange.Length - 1
    clientIP = ipRange(le)
Else
    clientIP = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim req As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp")        
Dim res As HttpWebResponse = req.GetResponse()
Dim Stream As Stream = res.GetResponseStream()
Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Stream)

MsgBox(sr.ReadToEnd())
```